# Best opening moves and tricks for invented 2-player board game: Pathways

Tags: board-size

I once invented a simple 2-player game called 'Pathways'.

**Rules**

There is a n x n grid. (Generally n>=8) Players alternate turns placing one marker per turn, on any empty slot of the board. The person who starts places an X and the other player uses O.  Two markers are considered to *be in the same path* only if they are horizontally/vertically adjacent to each other (not diagonally).

A person wins if he has created a continuous path of his markers that connects the top edge of the board to the bottom edge, or the left edge of the board to the right edge.

**Strategy**

*I would like to know whether there are any simple tricks a human can follow to become a good player (no computer algorithms or perfect strategies, please).*

Generally, I start with the slot 2 units diagonally away from the corner the opponent takes (my friends generally do). I play very offensively, and defend only when necessary to prevent a trap. So far, this has worked, but I've not played against any *really* good players, so I don't know. I've also noticed that it is possible for a person to guarantee his win long before he actually wins (like a series of checks in chess).

Comment: Are you familiar with Hex? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_%28board_game%29

Comment: I also recommend reading about the strategy-stealing argument. It shows why in a game like yours, the second player can never win unless the first player allows it through a mistake: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy-stealing_argument

Comment: just by doodling around on ms paint, it seems incredibly easy to force a draw.

Comment: @GendoIkari No, I didn't know about hex. The first player may have an advantage, but only a minor one. It may be possible for him to lose that advantage with only 1/2 imperfect moves. And I've specifically mentioned I'm not interested in *perfect strategy*, some good tactics that a human could follow are enough.

Comment: @user3453281 Yes, the first player can probably force a draw. But I am asking for tactics on how to win (especially if the opponent is also human, and makes errors).

Comment: I haven't worked through all the possibilities, but a major diagonal strategy seems unbeatable on an odd sized board (start in the middle), and seems to be at worst a draw on an even sized board.

Comment: @bwarner, what do you mean by major diagonal strategy? If you mean "take the opponent's last move and rotate it 180 degrees about the board's center", it seems to me that the second player can defeat the first by going straight up the rightmost column. Example game for N=3: B2, C2, A2, C1, A3, C3.

Comment: I meant focusing on trying to control the major diagonals.  Controlling an entire diagonal means your opponent can't win.  Controlling most of a diagonal limits what you need to block.